# Django Rest Framework: Overwriting validation error keys

Tags: python, django, validation, serialization, django-rest-framework

When translating my site to another language a problem occurred.
I want to handle Validation Errors properly and allow my front-end friends to display them well.

Is there a way to overwrite keys in response message of DRF when Validation Error happend?
What do I mean by that - I want to change this:

```
{
    "name": ["This field is required."]
}
```

into:

```
{
    "username": ["This field is required."]
}
```

Is there a way to do that without writing each and every one of validators?

Answer (score 3):

You can change the `name` field in the `ModelSerializer` to `username`.

example:

```
class CustomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(source='name')

    class Meta:
        model = ...
        fields = ('username', ...)
```

Now in validation errors it will have the key `username` instead.

Comment: The whole problem with this solution is the fact, that I would need to use different servers (and files) for different language versions. I want to avoid this situation.